# Power objects and direct images

Tags: category-theory

As the name suggests, the "power object" of an object should be thought of as an analogue of the standard notion of the powerset. If we consider a function $f: A \to B$ between two sets, it is easy to work with its direct image $Pf: P(A) \to P(B)$. Now, my question is if there exists an analogue of the direct image in the case of power objects.

Comment: You need to assume some more structure on your category to get a useful abstraction. A popular framework that has notions along the lines you are interested in is [topos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos).

Comment: Yes. You should read an introductory book on topos theory for a full explanation.

Comment: Also see Lemma 3 of http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/11/tr11.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is it possible to have a precise reference of some topos theory books dealing with such an issue? The paper above is interesting but it is strictly related to set-theoretic (and logic) perspectives. I need a book where what I'm requiring is explicitly written, if possible.